# asp.net user login question

Tags: asp.net, account

In an asp.net webform app, I need to restrict the logged in user to show data only for their company. This is a primary key of my topmost table. How to I set that based off the user. I imagine I would have another table with some user ID mapped to company ID?

Comment: You would use a mapping table if company has many users AND users have many companies. If your user has only one company, the users table has a foreign key column containing the primary key of the company.

Answer (score 0):

If a user can be part of exactly one company, then generally there would be a table of companies and a table of users, with the latter having a company ID foreign key column to the primary key of the former.  The user object would then have the company ID throughout the application (such as in the cookie data or session data) and the application would apply filtering rules accordingly.

Comment: sure, how would i wire up with the asp.net user. is there an object for the currently logged in user?

Comment: Are you using the Asp.Net Membership API?

Comment: @tim: That's going to depend a lot on how your application is currently set up.  I usually have the authentication request processed through custom domain models, one of which is a "User".  That custom model would have the company data in it and would follow the logged-in user by use of their session (validated from their cookie).

Comment: Yes, i am using the membership api. My question is how to i tie into that?

Comment: @Tim: I'm not 100% sure on how to use the membership DB alongside data  that is non-membership? Is it ok to build around the membership database or is there another table created in your enterprise database, for example Employee, that would map to it? I would suggest editing the title of your question to include ASP.Net Membership API. Surely someone with a lot of experience with it will be able to suggest the best way. As for me I don't know the best answer and will stick around to see. Good question!